# How do I use NTFS links to merge folders A and B?

Tags: ntfs, symbolic-link

To save on disk space and to keep things tidy, I want to have two folders, A and B. Folder A contains "stock" files, and Folder B contains "modded" files. I want to have the contents of Folder B in Folder A so as to have a "union."

For example, this is how the files are organized right now:

```
Folder A     Folder B
|            |
\-1          \-4
|            |
\-2          \-5
|            |
\-3          \-6
```

This is how I want them to be:

```
Folder A     Folder B
|            |
\-1  /-------\-4
|    |       |
\-2  |-------\-5
|    |       |
\-3  |-------\-6
|    |
\-4--/
|    |
\-5--/
|    |
\-6--/
```

You can do this easily with regular symlinks, but the catch is that when I add new files in Folder B, they should be automatically seen in Folder A as well.

How can I do this *without* using any manual scripts or extra software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. While I've often thought it would be handy, to the point of considering writing software to create one, most file systems (NTFS definitely included) do not support unifying two directories the way you ask.

There are a bunch of problems that you'd need to create some solution for. What happens if you add a file to one folder when a file of the same name already exists in the other folder, or try to add a new file/folder directly to the union (which parent does it appear inside)? What happens to the union if you delete one of the folders, or rename it? What happens if their permissions differ, so one folder is readable by user X but the other is not? All of these questions (and many more that will be encountered trying this) have potential answers, but which answer is best for a given use case or implementation method will differ.

Now, with that said, Windows (Vista and later) has the concept of a "Library" that can store files from multiple directories. For example, each user has a "Music" library that, by default, holds the union of their personal Music folder and also the public (all users) Music folder. Libraries have a bunch of limitations, the most notable of which is that they aren't actually in the file system at all - there's no path to them that you can put in a script, and you can't open a command prompt that points to one - but they might be useful nonetheless. For more info, read here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Working-with-libraries