# Make contents of folder A visible inside folder B?

Tags: windows, filesystems, symbolic-link

##### Requirements

I'm looking for a way to create folders with this behavior:

1. All content of `folder A` automatically appears within `folder B`
2. Changes in `folder A` (creating, modifying, deleting) are immediately reflected in `folder B`.
3. `folder B` can retain its own unique content unaffected by this system

##### Attempted Solutions

- **OverlayFS** - This is the ideal solution, but only works on Linux not Windows
- **symlink / junction** - If I make folder B with `mklink /D` pointing to folder A this meets requirements #1 and #2, but then it can't diverge from folder A and doesn't meet #3
- **Libraries** - Doesn't meet requirement #3 and can't act as a folder (ie. exist at a specific location on the file system)
- **FreeFileSync** - This tool syncs folders by comparing their content and copying any new/changed files between them. Automating this involves repeatedly executing a script via Task Scheduler. This has performance issues with large frequently-changing files, and also doesn't solve requirement #3.
- **RoboCopy** - Same problems as FreeFileSync.
- **Custom Script** - This is what I currently do. I have a Python script iterate over the top level contents of folder A then create symlinks to it in folder B while maintaining a list of them in JSON, then deleting them on the next run if they no longer exist in folder A. I'm looking for a better solution.

##### Motivation

I want this for cases where files/folders need to appear in a certain place but I want to keep them elsewhere for easy editing, backups, and git tracking. For example Git Bash needs `.bashrc` in `~` to work, but I want to keep it and its dependencies in `C:\_MyFiles\home_config`, so I want that folder's contents to appear inside `~`. Similarly, I want files under both `C:\_MyFiles\portable_apps` and `C:\_MyFiles\notes` to appear on my desktop.

I found some related questions below but the answers are very old or don't meet my needs.

- [Continuously copy all file changes from one folder to another on change (Windows)](https://superuser.com/questions/557132/continuously-copy-all-file-changes-from-one-folder-to-another-on-change-windows)
- [Make the contents of two folders appear in one](https://superuser.com/questions/674069/make-the-contents-of-two-folders-appear-in-one)
- [How do I use NTFS links to merge folders A and B?](https://superuser.com/questions/972510/how-do-i-use-ntfs-links-to-merge-folders-a-and-b)
- [Is there such a thing as an 'overlay mount', 'unionfs' or something similar in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/386430/is-there-such-a-thing-as-an-overlay-mount-unionfs-or-something-similar-in-w)

Comment: What's the problem : Looking for a better sync program or something else?

Comment: What you want just can't be done easily. You could simlink every folder and file of Folder A into Folder B, but any new file or folder in A will not be visible in B. FreeFileSync has RealTime Sync which will already work better for what you want, but any sync will have performance issues.

Comment: Probably the best performance option would be a powershell script that runs often, and creates symlinks for individual files and folders in folder B for any file or folder in Folder A that not already exists in Folder B.

Comment: @harrymc Ideally a feature to virtually mount folders similar to OverlayFS, where there is no file copying/duplication. Basically like a junction that can also store unique files inside itself the way a folder would.

Comment: @LPChip Yeah I suspected that, but hoped maybe there was something new since other answers I found saying "you can't" were 10 years old. Your PowerShell idea is similar to my current custom script workaround that I mentioned under attempted solutions

Comment: Making a symlink to folder A itself inside B seems the only easy solution.

Comment: This is for situations where files need to be in a certain place though - programs/scripts trying to `source ~/.bashrc` expect it to be at the root of the home dir not a subfolder. There are many similar scenarios (desktop icons, Steam saved games, Start Menu, startup, etc) where things need to exist at the root of some special folder, where being able to virtually mount contents of another folder directly into it would be very handy.

Comment: I have no experience with OverlayFS, but maybe Bash for windows (WSL) can run this.